# How to specify whether the windows is logged in or not in C# service application?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-services

I've implemented a service application, that works fine all the time, both when the user has logged in and when the windows is in log in mode, but need to know whether the user has been logged or windows is in logged off mode. how can i do that?

Comment: Why does your service need to know that?

Comment: It must log the current user name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enumerate the active logon sessions.

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088091/how-to-get-a-list-of-windows-sessions) may help.